# Send wav data to from Java to Cpp via string

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, wav

I need to be able to send a wav files to a background process in android, which is running my audio plugin code from a different package:  Samsung Audio SDK.

The only interface to the background process is to send strings - thus the solution seems to be to convert the wav to a string in Java, and reload it again in cpp. The format of the wavs can be fixed (it doesn't need to account for all possible parameters)

What would be a good way to go about this?  Plus are there any problems sending a gigantic string in this manner (i.e. should i break it into chunks?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this from the FAQ section on the [Samsung Website](http://developer.samsung.com/resources/professional-audio)

1. Copy file from java to the directory pointed to by 'getApplicationInfo().dataDir'.  I was having trouble using this method because I didn't set the file to be readable (e.g. outFile.setReadable(true,false); )
2. You can read the file by doing something like this (if your package is example.com):

   ```
   void readFile() {

       FILE* fp = fopen("/data/data/example.com/file_test_1.txt","r+");

       if(fp!=NULL)
       {
           // do something
           fclose(fp);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a character to separate each of the values so you can easily parse the string on the other side via splitting it up e.g. `"1,2,3" -> split on "," = "1" "2" "3"`

In your case I would first try to send the whole thing and see if there are any problems. If there are none... good, otherwise split the whole string into several pieces by size, but keeping the way you can split the values easily. Also you should watch that the encoding of the Strings is equal on both ends, otherwise you will have problems.